# Is numpy.array() an abstract data type?

Tags: python, numpy, data-structures

I recently read up on ADT. Based on my understanding I think `numpy.array()` is ADT because it just describes the behaviour ( by having set of functions made available) and acts as an interface by hiding all implementation details. So is `numpy.array()` an abstract type? If not, please explain.

**Edit- My understanding of ADT:**  Consider an example of array (static array) and stacks.
**Statement**: Array is not an abstract data structure but I consider stacks to be ADT.

**Reason :** Stacks is ADT because it provides a set of operations like push(), pop(), isFull(), isEmpty() etc. Further, the implementation of these operations of stack is hidden and may be different in different languages. Array is not ADT because Array doesn't have an abstract behaviour or operation, all it does is stores an element. Stacks, AVL, hashmaps uses these arrays to built thier own ADT

Comment: IMHO it's not possible to have abstract data types in Python at all. There's simply no keyword for it.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of an ADT?

Comment: Every class should hide all implementation details. Otherwise, they would not be implementation details.

Comment: Wikipedia says "integers are an ADT."  Do you subscribe to that definition?  If so, NumPy arrays are also ADTs.

Comment: Updated question with my understanding of ADT

Comment: ADT is a software engineering concept. An implementation like `np.ndarray` (`np.array` is a factory function) cannot, by definition, be "abstract", it is a specific implementation. Now, `np.ndarray` implements what could be called a "n-dimensional array ADT". There is no hard spec for such ADT, but you could think of one and write a "compatible implementation" (to some extent, you could say eager-mode TensorFlow offers something like that). In any case, ADTs are only useful for algorithmic design and complexity, and in that case you shouldn't be talking about `np.ndarray` concretely.